# Relationship between quad bayer sensor and the CMOS size

Tags: metadata, optics, cmos-image-sensor

[I have developed Python code](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gerry-gabrisch-gisp-2aa3263b_algorithm-based-automated-georeferencing-activity-6910658166561153024-M1gy?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop) to take an image produced by a DJI drone (and several other GNSS Cameras) and georeference the images.  Basically the code reads the EXIF data from the individual images.  A number of data are extracted from the EXIF like location, elevation, drone direction etc. and are use to create a footprint on the land.  The images is then warped (scaled, skewed, rotated, and rubbersheeted) to that footprint and given real-world coordinates.  The resulting image can be used in GIS software to determine/measure the relationship between what is on the ground and what is seen in the image.  This all works great with Phantom 3 Pro, Phantom 4 Pro (and V2), Mavics, Mini Mavics etc.  One important part of the code is that I need to code-in the CMOS sensor size.  [These sizes have been available online](https://www.dpreview.com/articles/4761655098/dji-s-mini-mini-2-mini-3-or-mini-3-pro-which-lightweight-drone-is-right-for-you).  I can confirm the reasonable accuracy of my methods with the drones mentioned above.

I now have a mini 3 pro.  After processing mini 3 pro images with my code I see that my resulting georeferenced image footprints are far larger that they should be.  This is a fail!  I found online that the CMOS sensor is(10 x 7.5mm).  I also understand that the mini 3 pro is capable of taking a 48 megapixel image but the images in my test are 12 MP images because that is what the drone captures in intervalometer mode.

Assuming the problem is with the 12MP images I reprocessed my test images using the same CMOS size as the  mini2  (6.4 x 4.7mm) which is also capturing a 12MP image.  The resulting footprints are still too large.  Again, I think I have the wrong sensor size.

Upon further investigation I see that this camera has a [quad bayer array](https://www.sony-semicon.com/en/technology/mobile/quad-bayer-coding.html).  I now understand that the issue with my code is that the inputs into my script are erroneous for this camera. As another experiment I tried dividing the 10x7.5 values by 4 and ran a test with 2.5 x 1.875.  That  produced an image too small for the landscape.

My question is which likely input parameter needs to change to get a 10x7.5 quad Bayer array to behave like a regular 6.4 x 4.7mm sensor?  Do I need to alter the CMOS size - that didn't work with the tests mentioned above, the focal length (which comes from the EXIF), the image size (which comes from the EXIF), some combination, or something else?  I am a geo-spatial analyst and not a optics guy so any help is appreciated.

Here is an EXIF dump from an image:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.88
File Name                       : DJI_0187.JPG
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 5.6 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2023:05:11 07:35:50-07:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2023:05:11 15:26:49-07:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2023:05:11 15:25:06-07:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Description               : default
Make                            : DJI
Camera Model Name               : FC3582
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : 10.02.22.06
Modify Date                     : 2023:05:11 14:35:49
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Co-sited
Exposure Time                   : 1/2000
F Number                        : 1.7
Exposure Program                : Program AE
ISO                             : 100
Sensitivity Type                : Recommended Exposure Index
Recommended Exposure Index      : 100
Exif Version                    : 0230
Date/Time Original              : 2023:05:11 14:35:49
Create Date                     : 2023:05:11 14:35:49
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/2000
Aperture Value                  : 1.7
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Max Aperture Value              : 1.7
Metering Mode                   : Average
Light Source                    : Daylight
Flash                           : No Flash
Focal Length                    : 6.7 mm
Warning                         : [minor] Bad MakerNotes directory
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 4032
Exif Image Height               : 3024
Interoperability Index          : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
Interoperability Version        : 0100
File Source                     : Digital Camera
Scene Type                      : Directly photographed
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
White Balance                   : Auto
Digital Zoom Ratio              : 1
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 24 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Gain Control                    : None
Contrast                        : Normal
Saturation                      : Normal
Sharpness                       : Normal
Device Setting Description      : (Binary data 4 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Serial Number                   : 53HQK7J0M103AX
Lens Info                       : 6.72mm f/1.7
GPS Version ID                  : 2.3.0.0
GPS Latitude Ref                : North
GPS Longitude Ref               : West
GPS Altitude Ref                : Below Sea Level
GPS Status                      : Measurement Void
GPS Map Datum                   : WGS-84
XP Comment                      : 0.9.142
XP Keywords                     : hdr
Compression                     : JPEG
Thumbnail Offset                : 25034
Thumbnail Length                : 9059
About                           : DJI Meta Data
Format                          : image/jpg
Image Source                    : DefaultCamera
Gps Status                      : Invalid
Altitude Type                   : RtkAlt
Absolute Altitude               : -19.028
Relative Altitude               : +27.900
Gimbal Roll Degree              : +0.00
Gimbal Yaw Degree               : -11.50
Gimbal Pitch Degree             : -89.90
Flight Roll Degree              : -4.00
Flight Yaw Degree               : -9.20
Flight Pitch Degree             : +2.50
Flight X Speed                  : 0.0
Flight Y Speed                  : 0.0
Flight Z Speed                  : 0.0
Cam Reverse                     : 0
Gimbal Reverse                  : 0
Self Data                       : 
Surveying Mode                  : 0
UTC At Exposure                 : 
Shutter Type                    : Electronic
Camera Serial Number            : 53HQK7J0M103AX
Lens Serial Number              : 
Drone Model                     : Mini 3 Pro
Drone Serial Number             : 1581F4XFA2322M
Version                         : 7.0
Has Settings                    : False
Has Crop                        : False
Already Applied                 : False
MPF Version                     : 0100
Number Of Images                : 2
MP Image Flags                  : Dependent child image
MP Image Format                 : JPEG
MP Image Type                   : Large Thumbnail (VGA equivalent)
MP Image Length                 : 263119
MP Image Start                  : 5659074
Dependent Image 1 Entry Number  : 0
Dependent Image 2 Entry Number  : 0
Image UID List                  : (Binary data 66 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Total Frames                    : 1
Image Width                     : 4032
Image Height                    : 3024
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Aperture                        : 1.7
Image Size                      : 4032x3024
Megapixels                      : 12.2
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 3.6
Shutter Speed                   : 1/2000
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 9059 bytes, use -b option to extract)
GPS Altitude                    : 19 m Below Sea Level
GPS Latitude                    : 48 deg 47' 26.85" N
GPS Longitude                   : 122 deg 37' 31.47" W
Preview Image                   : (Binary data 263119 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.008 mm
Field Of View                   : 73.7 deg
Focal Length                    : 6.7 mm (35 mm equivalent: 24.0 mm)
GPS Position                    : 48 deg 47' 26.85" N, 122 deg 37' 31.47" W
Hyperfocal Distance             : 3.16 m
Light Value                     : 12.5
```

Comment: The bayer array is square 2x2 so you should divide each dimension by 2, not 4

Comment: Ugh, math error on my part.  Thanks, that worked.  If you post that as an answer I will mark that answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is small mistake with the size of the Bayer matrix. It is 2x2 cells so you should divide each dimension by 2, not by 4.

P.S. for information [Fujifilm X-Trans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter#Fujifilm_%22X-Trans%22_filter) matrix is different, it is 3x3 so if you have/use such sensor you should change the calculations.